# Can the Worksheet.Range property be used to copy and paste values with a certain number format?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that copies and pastes (duplicates) an existing worksheet called *Line Item Summary* as a new worksheet. The original worksheet contains a table with values calculated from formulas, but I only need the values from the table to be copied over in the same worksheet layout.

Is there a way to modify my current code so that the worksheet values are pasted in the **Accounting format** ?

```
Sub FreezeLIS()

Call SaveAs
Call CopySheetFromClosedWB

'Values Only LIS
Worksheets("Line Item Summary").Copy After:=Worksheets("Line Item Summary")
Worksheets(Worksheets("Line Item Summary").Index + 1).Activate

    ActiveSheet.Range("B6:S100").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:S100").Value

'Active Tab
ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 15

End Sub
```

*Original Line Item Summary*: Uses the Accounting format and 2 decimal places.
[image]

*Copy of Line Item Summary Worksheet*: Defaults to the Currency format and 2 decimal places.
[image]

Comment: Just change the `Range.NumberFormat`.

Comment: @BigBen thank you for the tip! I wasn't able to execute it properly... ```ActiveSheet.Range("B6:S100").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B6:S100").Value.NumberFormat = "Accounting"```

Comment: Try using the macro recorder.

Comment: @icalderon That should be `ActiveSheet.Range("B6:S100").NumberFormat = "Accounting"` - `.NumberFormat` is not a property of `.Value`.

Comment: @dwirony - I don't think "Accounting" is a valid number format. I think the US version is `"_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"`.

Comment: @BigBen Oops, typo! I meant to type `"_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"` :) (haha not really, but what a fancy number format)!

Comment: This is closer to what I am looking for! The suggestion changes the table to the Accounting Format I need but now it is blank...I need the values copied from the original worksheet to the new sheet with the Accounting format